# ARM templates - web.config transform not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a website and sql azure using an Arm template and I am trying to get the sql connection string to be transformed with the deployed website using the deployed database name. the website is created, source deployed and sql azure database are created but the connection string does not get changed though.
I have followed the method here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-sql-database

My website.json looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "integration",
        "qa"
      ]
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "F1",
      "allowedValues": [
        "F1",
        "D1",
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "skuCapacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 1,
      "minValue": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's instance count"
      }
    },
    "sqlserverAdminLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "sqlserverAdminLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "databaseCollation": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    },
    "databaseEdition": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ]
    },
    "databaseRequestedServiceObjectiveName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Basic",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "S0",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes the performance level for Edition"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "webSiteName": "[concat('webSite-MyApp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "sqlserverName": "[concat('sqlserver-', parameters('environmentName'), '-',  uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "HostingPlan"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('skuCapacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
          "type": "config",
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('webSiteName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "DefaultConnection": {
              "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', parameters('databaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('sqlserverAdminLogin'), '@', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ';Password=', parameters('sqlserverAdminLoginPassword'), ';')]",
              "type": "SQLAzure"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('sqlserverName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "SqlServer"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlserverAdminLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqlserverAdminLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
          "type": "databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Database"
          },
          "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('sqlserverName')]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "edition": "Basic",
            "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
            "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
            "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "Basic"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('sqlserverName')]"
          ],
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "siteUri": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))).hostnames[0]]"
    },
    "sqlServerFullyQualifiedDomain": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
    }
  }
}
```

My parameter file is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "value": "MyAppIntegration"
    },
    "environmentName": {
      "value": "integration"
    },
    "sqlserverAdminLogin": {
      "value": "azureuser"
    },
    "sqlserverAdminLoginPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/MyAppVault"
        },
        "secretName": "SqlAzurePassword"
      }
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "value": "myapp-integration" 
    }
  }
}
```

and my web.config looks like this:

```
ml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyApp-20170201054732.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyApp-20170201054732;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Can anyone tell me why the DefaultConnection never changes?

Answer (score 1):

I've just deployed it and can confirm that the application settings gets populated properly. `Web.config` should not get overwritten with this template, the template creates application settings, which the app reads:

If the application setting(s) happen to already exist in your web.config file, Windows Azure Web Sites will automatically override them at runtime using the values associated with your website. Connection strings work in a similar fashion, with a small additional requirement.  Remember from earlier that there is a connection string called “example-config_db” that has been associated with the website.  If the website’s web.config file references the same connection string in the  configuration section, then Windows Azure Web Sites will automatically update the connection string at runtime using the value shown in the portal.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Comment: I did the same with some appSettings and the template overwrote them with deployment settings fine. I still don't understand why it doesn't work here. I have followed the template used by Microsoft. What do you mean 'remember from earlier' and where have you got example-config_db from? I don't want to use the portal, I want to use a deployment template and dynamically fill in the connection string based on the database which azure creates.

Comment: The way Azure has done this is really confusing. I can overwrite a variable in AppSettings using an ARM template but a connection string will not overwrite but will be invisibly used behind the scenes as you identify above. The web.config remains unchanged.

Comment: yeah, that appears to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Your `DefaultConnection` connection string in the `web.config` does not get updated via your ARM deployment simply because you actually need to deploy the web.config file as part of a MSDeploy package with a parameter for updating the `DefaultConnection` connection string, using the MSDeploy extension resource in the ARM Template.

E.g. In your MSDeploy Package parameters.xml, you need to define a parameter to allow updating the value for the connection string with the name  `DefaultConnection`.

```
  <parameter name="Default Connection String" description="Connection string to enter into config" tags="SQL, Hidden,NoStore">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web\.config$" match="//connectionStrings/add[@name='DefaultConnection']/@connectionString" />
  </parameter>
```

In addition to the above, you will also need to add the **MSDeploy extension** resource, which is a child resource under your website resource and set the **Default Connection String** parameters with your Azure SQL connection string in your ARM Template.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  },
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "MSDeploy",
        "type": "extensions",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
        ],
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "webDeploy"
        },
        "properties": {
            "packageUri": "[parameters('MSDeployPackageUri')]", 
            "dbType": "None",
            "connectionString": "",
            "setParameters": {
                "Application Path": "[variables('webSiteName')]",
                "Default Connection String": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', parameters('databaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('sqlserverAdminLogin'), '@', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlserverName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ';Password=', parameters('sqlserverAdminLoginPassword'), ';')]"
            }
        }
    }
],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "Website"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
},...
```

Reference: [Deploy a web app with MSDeploy, custom hostname and SSL certificate](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't have to do any of this to override an appSetting variable. Why is this so different for a connection string?

Comment: This is because the connection string settings for the Azure App Service has higher precedence over the connection string settings defined in the web.config, hence they do not need to update the connection strings in the web.config

Comment: I'm not using the connection strings in azure app service

Comment: No you did. In your Arm Template, you're defining the connection string config type resource under your website

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I want to do is overwrite the connection string in web.config in the same way I did for appSettings. Does what you describe above do this?

Comment: It is not possible today, the only way to update connection strings in the web.config via ARM deployment is via the MSDeploy extension.

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you? I think I've tried to provide what I know best today for the suggested solution to your question. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. yes, I need time to try it out and see if there are any other points of view. I am surprised connection string transformation is not allowed by appSetting transformation is but will give your suggestion a go

Comment: Why won't this approach work? https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-define-web-app-connection-strings/